# Как добавить данные в базу MySQL из DataGrid C#?

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, база-данных, datagrid

Как добавить данные вводимые в DataGrid в базу данных MySQL? Добавленных данных нет в базе, и ошибок, почему это происходит тоже нет. Я пытаюсь решить эту проблему уже несколько дней. Использую WPF.

```
private void dtGrid_RowEditEnding(object sender, DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs e)
    {    
    MySqlConnection conn = DBUtils.GetDBConnection();
    string table = "brands";
    string sql = "SELECT * FROM "+table;
    MySqlDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
    conn.Open();
    MySqlCommandBuilder myCommandBuilder = new MySqlCommandBuilder(myDataAdapter);
    myDataAdapter.InsertCommand = myCommandBuilder.GetInsertCommand();
    myDataAdapter.UpdateCommand = myCommandBuilder.GetUpdateCommand();
    myDataAdapter.DeleteCommand = myCommandBuilder.GetDeleteCommand();
    DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
    myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, table);
    myDataAdapter.AcceptChangesDuringUpdate = true;
    myDataAdapter.Update(myDataSet, table);
    conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: оно ли? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14065443/updating-database-using-datagridview

Comment: посмотрите здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/900352/261244

Comment: @Andrew, там под Windows Forms

Comment: @ЕвгенийКрасильников Если вы не можете адаптировать код с WinForms под WPF, то может вам стоит начать изучение языка с чего то более простого?

Comment: @ЕвгенийКрасильников EvgeniyZ прав. Адаптация кода с WinForms на WPF это просто на столько базовый скил, что тебе явно нужно еще изучать язык перед тем, как делать подобные задачи как в вопросе. Ответ я подсказал, но с адаптацией кода игратся за тебя я чет не очень хочу)

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что вы в коде никак не задействуете DataGrid. Вы создаете пустой DataSet, заполняете его данными из базы, и потом *эти же самые данные* записываете назад в базу. Правильно нужно делать так:

Допустим, мы хотим сделать DataGrid, привязанную к DataTable. Сразу в конструкторе окна создадим DbDataAdapter и DataTable (нет необходимости это делать при каждом обновлении, так как структура данных и запросы то не меняются), и сохраним их в полях класса окна.

```
DbDataAdapter adapter;
DataTable dt;

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    MySqlConnection conn = DBUtils.GetDBConnection();
    string table = "brands";
    string sql = "SELECT * FROM "+table;
    adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
    conn.Open();
    MySqlCommandBuilder myCommandBuilder = new MySqlCommandBuilder(adapter as MySqlDataAdapter);
    adapter.InsertCommand = myCommandBuilder.GetInsertCommand();
    adapter.UpdateCommand = myCommandBuilder.GetUpdateCommand();
    adapter.DeleteCommand = myCommandBuilder.GetDeleteCommand();            

    dt = new DataTable();
    adapter.Fill(dt); //загрузка данных
    datagrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView; //привязка к DataGrid

}
```

Теперь, когда нужно сохранить данные (я не рекомендую сохранять при каждом изменении строки, так как будет слишком много запросов в базу, лучше создать кнопку "Сохранить"), выполним Update на *той же* DataTable.

```
private void ButtonSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{            
    adapter.Update(dt);
}
```